# How to make a div with position fixed only fixed for vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with the id menu-header, the div has a position fixed. The only problem is that I only want to give it a position: fixed for the y-as (vertical scroll) and not for the x-as (horizontal scroll). How can I do this in javascript or jquery

This worked:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('#globalnav').css('left',-$(window).scrollLeft());
  $('#globalborder').css('left',-$(window).scrollLeft());
  $('#backgroundlayer').css('left',-$(window).scrollLeft());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Position doesn't work that way, it can't be vertically fixed and horizontally relative.

Comment: Maybe it is possible with javascript or query

Comment: I tried this: http://www.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/

Comment: But can't get it working

Comment: Can you share the solution please?